# ASP.NET Core 8 with Google Sign-In StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 8 application using Identity for authentication, including Google sign-in. After successfully signing in with Google, the application redirects to /signin-google, but this results in an unhandled exception:
(Access token and refresh token are well generated and works)
[Exception screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0akO.png)
System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)

Here's my AuthController:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;
        private readonly SignInManager<MyUser> _signInManager;

        public AuthController(
            ILogger<AuthController> logger,
            SignInManager<MyUser> signInManager)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpGet("google")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(
                GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, null);
            return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

And my Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme)
                .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
                {
                    googleOptions.ClientId = "client";
                    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "secret";
                })
                .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase("AuthNet8"));

            builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<MyUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddApiEndpoints();

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            var app = builder.Build();

            app.MapGet("/", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity.Name}")
            .RequireAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

What could be causing this InvalidOperationException and how can I fix it? Any ideas ?

I've tried modifying the middleware order, but the problem persists.

Comment: This issue commonly arises when passing HttpContext to the next delegate after a middleware has already written a response. You can check the [link](https://www.appsloveworld.com/csharp/100/37/asp-net-core-middleware-cannot-set-status-code-on-exception-because-response-has) for more details.

Comment: @Ivan I agree with you, but given the simplicity of the code, I don't see where this can come from. There's no custom middleware. The code shown in my post is the full project code.